# How to apply definite integral on $\sqrt{1+\sin x}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to solve the following integral:

$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+\sin x} \, dx$$

I want to do this with the substitution:

$$u=\sin x$$

so that:

$$du=\cos x\,dx=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}\,dx = \sqrt{1-u^2} \, dx$$

$$dx = \frac{du}{1-u^2}$$

$$u(0) = 0, \quad u(\pi/2)=1, \quad u(\pi)=0$$

$$\int\sqrt{1+\sin x} \, dx = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}} \, du = -2\sqrt{1-u}$$

So since $u$ isn't defined for 1 (corresponding $x$ is $\pi/2$), I split the integration to ($0, \pi/2$) and ($\pi/2, \pi$)
However when I assign the substitution I get:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}} \, du + \int_1^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}} \, du = 2-2 = 0$$

But the result should be $4.$ It seems like I should flip the sign here for some reason but I can't figure it out, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to specifically know why my substitution fails".  (OP quoted from a comment on a now-deleted answer.  I agree that it would have been nice for OP to actually put his question in the Question.)

$$  \cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}  $$
is only true when $\cos x \geq 0$ (because the radical on the right-hand side is always nonnegative).  This fails for $x \in (\pi/2, \pi]$.  In that interval, you need the other choice of sign of the radical , which gives your missing minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \sqrt{1+\sin x} dx= \int (\sin(x/2)+ \cos(x/2)) dx=2[\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)]+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\pi}\root{1 + \sin\pars{x}}\dd x} =
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\root{1 + \cos\pars{x}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\root{1 + \cos\pars{x}}\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\root{1 + \bracks{2\cos^{2}\pars{x \over 2} - 1}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
2\root{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{x \over 2}\,\dd x =
2\root{2}\,{\sin\pars{\pi/4} \over 1/2} = \bbx{4} \\ &
\end{align}